# Ajax file download over GET not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, chromium, opera

This code works in all major browsers excpet in latest Opera 71 (Windows).
The behaviour is that no error or info shows up but the download never starts from end user perspective. In developer tools I see the binary content of the example pdf document in response tab.

It seems that the dynamic creation of tags is not working.

```
function downloadFile(urlToSend) {
         var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
         req.open("GET", urlToSend, true);
         req.responseType = "blob";
         req.onload = function (event) {
             var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
             var contentType = req.getResponseHeader('content-type');
             var blob = new Blob([req.response], {type: contentType});
             var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             
             var contentDisposition = req.getResponseHeader('content-disposition');
             
             
             //var fileName = req.getResponseHeader("fileName") //if you have the fileName header available
             var filename = 'doku.pdf'; //contentDisposition.match(/filename*="(.+)"/)[1];
             
             if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    //code which gets executed by Opera
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            }
             
        };
        req.send();
    }
```